# Make an RSS feed for the things posted to twitter

Tags: feature-request, chat, twitter

Hot questions get posted to twitter.  Sometimes, people want to see what they are without having a twitter feed running (corporate work filtering, aversion to twitter, or what have you)... but do have chat up and running.  This gives mods and active users the ability to see what questions are posted to twitter and address the issue (protect them) if it is something that may get too much attention.

Given the ArsTechnica attention, that feed is attached to at least one chat room so that we can get an idea of what is happening there if the question needs additional attention by active, trusted users.

The [current twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview) says thus:

> API v1.1 will support JSON only. We've been hinting at this for some time now, first dropping XML support on the Streaming API and more recently on the trends API. We've chosen to throw our support behind the JSON format shared across the platform. **Consequently, we've decided to discontinue support for XML, Atom, and RSS, which are infrequently used today.** For historical context, when we originally built the API all major languages did not have performant, well vetted libraries supporting JSON — today they do.

**Request**:  Make a RSS or atom feed that can be consumed by the chat.

We've got the things before they become twitter posts... make it an rss feed.

Various random ideas that are completely devoid of the knowledge of the internal workings of SE's system...

- Make a special tag of [se-twitter](/questions/tagged/se-twitter) or something that can then be programmatically added to the questions as they are tweeted.  Tags already have rss feeds and can be consumed in chat.
- Do a 'proper' rss feed that contains links to twitter posts as they are created.  Store that for the site so that XYZ.StackExchange.com/twitter.rss contains the information and it nicely oneboxes the twitter posts (useful for separating the sources of the automatically posted messages).

<sub>Alternate request: Modify chat feeds to consume the twitter API (which doesn't have atom or rss as part of it).</sub>

Comment: A meta tag for everything tweeted? *No.* I'd rather just see them add in support for a JSON feed in some way. Seems a bit of a waste to just create their own feed.

Comment: @animuson a magical unseen meta tag thats never really there on the site proper... Adding the tweeted tag and invisibility on it may be the fastest/simplest way to get something that works... if that was a possibly viable option.  I didn't say that approach is a *good* idea, just one that I could see that might get some dev thinking that would say "oh yea, if I did something like that it would only take me 30 minutes and wouldn't be bad"

Comment: So SE pushes stuff to Twitter, and then pulls it *back* from Twitter to post into chat rooms? Why not cut out the middleman?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen that's certainly one approach.  The information *is* known somewhere (its in the edit history but not the timeline).  One approach is if SE would publish its own feed of what goes to twitter as an rss feed for the site... somehow. I'd just like to see whats posted in chat.